# Reflection and Lighting Problem : Donut

Tags: workflow, light, lighting

[image: This is how my cup looks.]
The first image is my blender work space but i want it to look like the second image.

[image: This is how it should look.]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the Glossy and Diffuse shaders connected the opposite way around compared to the tutorial screenshot. This means (with mix factor or 0.09) your material is far more glossy than diffuse. Either increase the Mix factor closer to 1.0 or swap the Mix input nodes around. The mix works by mixing between the inputs with 0.0 being completely the first input, 1.0 being completely the second input, and inbetween values mixing gradually between the two.